# How to check in a particular model by default in haystack?

Tags: django, django-haystack

i am using haystack for searching. By default it searches in all the models and then provides the checklist of models indexed to refine search. Is there a way i can override this functionality i.e can i make it search in a particular model by default?? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [override ModelSearchForm](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/views_and_forms.html#creating-your-own-form) to do this, try something like the below, replacing app_label.model_name with the model(s) you wish to search by default.

```
class CustomModelSearchForm(ModelSearchForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModelSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['models'].initial = ["app_label.model_name",]

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', SearchViewg(form_class=CustomModelSearchForm, name='haystack_search'),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the models method from SearchQuerySet:

http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html#models

or use the reserved field name django_ct like this:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(django_ct='app_name.model_name')
```